# How far should I go with puppet?

Tags: puppet

I'd like to preface by saying I'm new to puppet.  I have been working with it via `vagrant` and am starting to feel comfortable writing manifests, but I lack perhaps the experience, or intuition, that can answer my question.

I am trying to grasp how puppet is scoped, and where lines are drawn.  I am specifically interested in how this applies to modules and their creation and use.

A more concrete example: the `puppletlabs-nginx` module.  So hypothetically I'm going along my merry way, creating a manifest for a given server role; say it's a dead-simple static file webserver, and I'd like to use `nginx`.  The module will clearly help me with that; there's `try_files` support and such.  I can even ramp up to reverse-proxying via this module.  But what if things get stickier?  What if there's something I want to do programmatically that I cannot do with the module?

Well, perhaps the short answer is to fix it myself, do a pull request, and go along my merry way.  But where does that stop?  Is the goal of a community puppet module to support every facet of a given software package?  That seems unmanageable.  On the other hand, doesn't that create a bunch of mostly-baked modules, build solely from use cases?

Then, there's an analog to Android UI: there are setter methods for what I think is most XML UI definitions.  In puppet if feels similar.  You can build a config file programmatically, or create it by filling in an ERB template.  In other words, I feel the line in puppet between programmatic creation of configuration files and the templated creation of configuration files is blurred; I found no best way with Android and so I don't know which is the way to go with puppet.

**So, to the question:** what constitutes the ideal puppet module?  Should it rely more on templates?  On the manifest?  Should it account for all configuration scenarios?

From a further-withdrawn perspective it almost seems I want something more opinionated.  Puppet's power seems to be flexibility and abstraction, but the modules that are out there feel inconsistent and not as fleshed out.

Thanks for reading...

Comment: Your concerns seem to mirror those who have switched to [Chef](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Home).

Comment: Have definitely seen Chef; haven't investigated as far.  Can you give an example?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Mark.  In just a small amount of time I've switched over to playing with Chef and the modules seem better in regards to many of the concerns I voiced.

Answer (score 1):

In short i can explain you about puppet.

Puppet is nothing but it is an IT automation tool where we can install software's on other machines by creating manifests (recipes or scripts) on master for those softwares to be installed on target machine.
Here master indicates implementation of puppet manifests for softwares.
     Target machine indicates agent where softwares to be installed.

Puppet module constitutes of following structure where we do this in master.

In master the path is /etc/puppet/modules to enter into modules directory,you have mentioned puppletlabs-nginx module.so now we can take this module as an example.

After modules directory we have to create files and manifests directories.furthermore,in manifests directory we will create .pp files.For instance, install.pp,uninstall.pp.this is how module structure will be.we usually run these scripts by using  few resources like package,service,file,exec etc.

Templates play a minor role in puppet manifests just to hardcore the values.it is not a major part of puppet.Manifests has a great importance in puppet.

For automating any software by using puppet we can follow the above structure.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The PuppetLabs solution here is to use different types of modules for each function -- Components, Profiles, and Roles.  See the presentation [Designing Puppet: Roles/Profiles Pattern](https://puppetlabs.com/presentations/designing-puppet-rolesprofiles-pattern) for more information.

The modules available from PuppetForge are of the "Component" type.  Their purpose is to be as flexible as possible, while focusing on a single logical piece of software -- e.g., either the apache httpd server OR apache tomcat, but not both.

The kinds of modules that you might write to wrap around one of those Component modules would be a perfect example of a "Profile" module.  This could tie apache httpd together along with tomcat and jboss and maybe also some other components like mysql and php.  But it's one logical stack, with multiple components.  Or maybe you have a LAMP Profile module, and a separate tomcat+jboss Profile module.

The next level up is "Role" modules.  They shouldn't have anything in them other than "include" statements that point at the appropriate Profile modules.

See the PuppetLabs presentation for more details, but this logic is pretty similar to what is seen in the Chef world with "wrapper cookbooks".